# Apache Nifi PutElasticSearch,unable to load data

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I am trying to load document in elastic search using `PutElasticSearch` , but getting below error when I see the bulletin board.

Cluster Name,ElasticSearch Hosts,Index and Type have been correctly configured.

```
   2016-05-25 09:56:03,053 WARN [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-6] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig The configuration partitioner.class = null was supplied but isn't a known config.
2016-05-25 09:56:03,053 INFO [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled PutKafka[id=78ae8c7e-7d95-45ad-a275-8004c451d622] to run with 1 threads
2016-05-25 09:56:03,418 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@560b3337 // Another save pending = false
2016-05-25 09:56:05,276 INFO [pool-16-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2016-05-25 09:56:05,418 INFO [pool-16-thread-1] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@5f61338 checkpointed with 483 Records and 0 Swap Files in 141 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 28 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 32 millis), max Transaction ID 7360
2016-05-25 09:56:05,418 INFO [pool-16-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 483 records in 141 milliseconds
2016-05-25 09:56:07,406 DEBUG [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-5] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch PutElasticsearch[id=0ba8a441-dcd9-4049-a11f-f04ee93b5d98] Creating ElasticSearch Client
2016-05-25 09:56:07,406 DEBUG [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-5] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch PutElasticsearch[id=0ba8a441-dcd9-4049-a11f-f04ee93b5d98] No Shield plugin location specified, secure connections and/or authorization will not be available
2016-05-25 09:56:07,411 INFO [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-5] org.elasticsearch.plugins [General Orwell Taylor] loaded [], sites []
2016-05-25 09:56:07,412 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-2] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch PutElasticsearch[id=0ba8a441-dcd9-4049-a11f-f04ee93b5d98] PutElasticsearch[id=0ba8a441-dcd9-4049-a11f-f04ee93b5d98] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30000 milliseconds: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
2016-05-25 09:56:07,443 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller task execution stopped abnormally
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine.afterExecute(FlowEngine.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1247) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.getTransportClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:292) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.createElasticsearchClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.setup(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch.setup(PutElasticsearch.java:143) ~[na:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
2016-05-25 09:56:07,446 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@560b3337 // Another save pending = false
2016-05-25 09:56:07,449 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-2] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1405) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.access$100(StandardProcessorNode.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:202) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1388) ~[na:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1247) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.getTransportClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:292) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.createElasticsearchClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.setup(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch.setup(PutElasticsearch.java:143) ~[na:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
2016-05-25 09:56:07,456 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-2] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1405) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.access$100(StandardProcessorNode.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:202) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1388) ~[na:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1247) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.getTransportClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:292) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.createElasticsearchClient(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.setup(AbstractElasticsearchProcessor.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch.setup(PutElasticsearch.java:143) ~[na:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which version of NiFi and Java are you using?  If you turn on the debug logging level, are there any PutElasticSearch entries preceeding this error?

Comment: Nifi Version: 0.6.1 Java: 1.7.0_45: Updated the log with debug level above.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using?